# If statement not comparing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

As stated, i'm sure this is a simple mistake starting me in the face, but I'm having trouble figuring out why my variable newState, when explicitly set to the string 'F1', does not trigger the else condition of the:   if newState == 'F1'...

I suppose I didn't need to port so much code over, sorry.

```
 (EOL, LETTER, DIGIT, PERIOD, ILLEGAL_CHAR, LEGAL_CHAR) = range(0, 6)


STT = [ ['error', 1, 2, 0, 'error', 0], ['F1', 1, 1, 'F1', 'error', 'F1' ], 
['F2', 'F2', 2, 3, 'error', 'F2'], ['error', 'error', 4, 'error', 'error', 'error'],
['F3', 'F3', 4, 'F3', 'error', 'F3']  ]

for line in open("Sample.txt","r"):
    x1 = ''
    currState = 0
    newState = 'F1'
    for char in line:
        if newState != 'F1' or newState != 'F2' or newState != 'F3' or newState != 'error':
            currState = newState
            #If eol
            if char == '\n':
                response = EOL
                newState = STT[currState][response]
                break
            #if letter
            elif char.isalpha():
                x1 = x1 + char
                response = LETTER
                newState = STT[currState][response]
               # break
            #if Digit
            elif char.isdigit():
                x1 = x1 + char
                response = DIGIT
                newState = STT[currState][response]
            #if Period
            elif char == '.':
                x1 = x1 + char
                response = PERIOD
                newState = STT[currState][response]                       
            #If illegal char set
            elif (char == '~' or char == '?' or char == ':' or char == '_' or char == '\\' ):
                response = ILLEGAL_CHAR
                newState = STT[currState][response]
                break
                                           # elif x1 != '':  
                                                #response = 5
                                               # newState = STT[currState][response]
                                               # break
            #if any other legal char
            else:
                response = LEGAL_CHAR
                newState = STT[currState][response]        
        #We have a token
        else:
            getToken(newState, x1)
```

Comment: Because it satisfies the other conditions like `newstate != 'F2'` - maybe you meant to "and" those conditions together?

Comment: I see `if newState != "F1"` but no comparison to ==.

Comment: wow, obviously thank you

Comment: user2079828: why would you delete your question's code? The answers are pretty impossible to make sense of now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `newstate` is F1, it will not trigger the else, because `newState != 'F2'` will trigger.

In the first if, try making it

```
if (not(newState == 'F1' or newState == 'F2' or newState == 'F3' or newState == 'error')):
```

The problem is

```
if !A or !B or ...
```

is not the same as

```
if !(A or B or...)
```

which is equal to

```
if (!A and !B and ...)
```

By DeMorgans law.

Comment: I'm sure that's not true, it's a common gotcha.

Comment: Consider using `if newState not in ['F1, 'F2', F3', 'error']` to increase readability.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of the above suggestion because newstate can take an arbitrary value, but @SteinerLimas comment is using set membership testing. It's sort of "abusive notation" mathematically. It's like using "if `booleanVariable` in `[False]`; its strange mathematically. Normally the `x in` clause should be used when x can be one of a finitely countable set.