# Why does my string comparison fail on the first test?

Tags: python

If I enter, h or l, c It keeps prompting me to enter a number instead of going to the correct case.

```
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100! "); 

low = 0;
high = 100
mid = 50

while True:
    print("Is your secret number " + str(mid) + "?")
    guess = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")

    if (guess != "h") or (guess != "l") or (guess != "c"):
         print "Sorry, I did not understand your input."   
         print "Is your secret number %i?" % mid
         guess = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")
    elif  guess == 'l':
         low = mid
    elif  guess == 'h':
         high = mid
    else:
         print "Game over. Your secret number was: %c" % mid 
         break          
    mid = (high + low) / 2
```

Comment: `(guess != "h") or (guess != "l") or (guess != "c")` what do you think the value of this is if guess is `"h"`? (`False or True or True`) -> use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: You should also be stripping the trailing newline with (e.g.) `guess = guess.rstrip('\n')` right after the `raw_input()` line.

Comment: @DSM: Why not?  OP is directly comparing strings, not using `str.startswith()` and friends.

Comment: Thank you. that make sense now.   Any ideas on how I can optimize my code better?

Comment: @Kevin: try `raw_input` at the console yourself.

Comment: I swear I just saw effectively the same question the other day. Can't find the dupe, though. Maybe it wasn't Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If statement not comparing properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760588/if-statement-not-comparing-properly)

Answer (score 3):

Your condn exp is wrong, it should be

```
if (guess != "h") and (guess != "l") and (guess != "c"):
```

This means that if the value is not `h` and `l` and `c` then execute. Your statement instead implied that if the input is not `h` or `l` or `c` then execute. So when you give `h` as input it fails as it is not `l` and `c`

Or as mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074291/why-does-my-string-comparison-fail-on-the-first-test/28074335#comment44527960_28074335), you can instead do,

```
if guess not in ['h', 'l', 'c']:
```

Comment: or simply `if guess not in ['h', 'l', 'c']`